# Telling when the user has finished entering text in a GtkComboBoxText

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I've created a GtkComboBoxText using gtk_combo_box_text_new_with_entry. When I type into it, the "changed" callback is called for every letter.
How can I tell when the user has finished their entry?

I'd be happy to require the user to press 'Enter' at the end, but that *doesn't* call the callback.

(I'm using GTK+2.)

Answer (score 0):

(Stackoverflow suggested another Q&A which put me on the path to enlightenment. I hadn't seen it while searching before I wrote my Q.)

It boils down to
`g_signal_connect(gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(cb))/*entry*/, "activate", G_CALLBACK(entryActivated), NULL);` where *cb* is the GtkComboBoxText (GtkWidget*). The callback is called when 'Enter' is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter in a GtkComboBoxText that has an entry causes the child GtkEntry to emit the activate signal.

> If the GtkComboBoxText contains an entry (via the 'has-entry' property), its contents can be retrieved using gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(). The entry itself can be accessed by calling gtk_bin_get_child() on the combo box.
>
> https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate

The combo box might be considered as part of a form that has its own apply button.

You can also connect to GtkWidget signals. I can't say which event but there is one that is emitted when a widget loses keyboard focus to another widget in the same window. This would allow save on tab out. This is distinct from the window losing focus to another window which is a signal emitted on the GtkWindow. As the widget that has focus in the window does not change when a window loses focus.